# Selenium Chromedriver is creating multiple instances when only one is wanted

Tags: c#, selenium, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I apologize if I come across naïve, I am new to Selenium and still learning.

We are attempting to run these selenium tests on a designated machine via IIS.

When I run the code locally, everything works perfectly. When I publish it to our machine, two instances of chromedriver will show up in the taskmanager when it is only being run once. Sometimes it will close one of the instances, while other times it doesn't close either. Sometimes it will even close both instances and work just fine. I can not figure out why it's being so inconsistent.

Here is a screen shot of the task manager after starting the code.

[image: Task Manager Screen Shot]

Any suggestions on this is welcome, below is the code I am running.

```
private IWebDriver _driver;

[Route("/Test_SignIn")]
public IActionResult Test_SignIn(string environment = "development")
{
    string response = "Failed";

    try
    {
        string outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        _driver = new ChromeDriver(outPutDirectory);

        if (environment == "production")
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(productionUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(developmentUrl);
        }

        By userNameFieldLocator = By.Id("AccountUserName");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(userNameFieldLocator));
        _waitForLoaderToFinish();
        IWebElement userNameField = _driver.FindElement(userNameFieldLocator);
        IWebElement passwordField = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("AccountPassword"));
        IWebElement signInButton = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Sign In')]"));
        userNameField.SendKeys(_username);
        passwordField.SendKeys(_password);
        signInButton.Click();
        By dashboardLocator = By.Id("portalBanner_EmployeeName");

        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(dashboardLocator));

        IWebElement dashboard = _driver.FindElement(dashboardLocator);
        response = "Success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = ex.Message;
    }

    _driver.Close();
    _driver.Quit();

    return Json(response);
}

private string _waitForLoaderToFinish()
{
    try
    {
        new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id("loader-wrapper")));

        return null;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        return $"{e.Message}";
    }
}
```

Comment: If quitting driver is not happening properly you will see the instance on task manager. Will that causing any issue to your tests? If yes then try this kill instance of driver at end of the test. In java, I use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM ChromeDriver.exe");`

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly! I did try this, but main issue was that we had chrome.exe running and killing the CPU. We have other tools using chrome, so I didn't want to kill all the processes. I do appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChromeDriver (and all other web drivers) are "disposable" objects in .NET. They implement the [IDisposable interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-5.0). Objects that implement this interface require special handling in order to clean up after they are finished. Typically you see these objects initialized in a `using(...)` block, similar to below:

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(...))
{
    // Use driver
}
```

Reference: [C# Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

I see that you are closing and quitting the browser, but you need to call `_driver.Dispose();` as well. The quick and easy way to accomplish this in your code is to call Dispose() after calling Quit():

```
_driver.Close();
_driver.Quit();
_driver.Dispose(); // <-- this kills Chrome.exe

return Json(response);
```

Or modify the method to wrap the use of `_driver` in a `using(...)` statement:

```
[Route("/Test_SignIn")]
public IActionResult Test_SignIn(string environment = "development")
{
    string response = "Failed";

    try
    {
        string outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        // Your web driver is a LOCAL variable now, beware!
        using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(outPutDirectory))
        {
            if (environment == "production")
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(productionUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(developmentUrl);
            }

            By userNameFieldLocator = By.Id("AccountUserName");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(userNameFieldLocator));
            _waitForLoaderToFinish();
            IWebElement userNameField = driver.FindElement(userNameFieldLocator);
            IWebElement passwordField = driver.FindElement(By.Id("AccountPassword"));
            IWebElement signInButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Sign In')]"));
            userNameField.SendKeys(_username);
            passwordField.SendKeys(_password);
            signInButton.Click();
            By dashboardLocator = By.Id("portalBanner_EmployeeName");

            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(dashboardLocator));

            IWebElement dashboard = driver.FindElement(dashboardLocator);
            response = "Success";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = ex.Message;
    }

    return Json(response);
}
```

Please note that your web driver becomes a **local variable** now. It should not be a field on the class in order to prevent other methods from accessing this disposable resource.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I have adapted the code to use `using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(outPutDirectory))` and it is still creating multiple processes until the CPU is at 100%. The test is working now, but is there any reason for it to be creating multiple processes? I'm not very familiar with IIS, but could it be a problem with that?

Comment: You get one controller object per request to the server. Each request creates a new instance of ChromeDriver. You don't want to share ChromeDriver instances across requests unless you set up a manager object that pools the ChromeDrivers and returns a driver that is free. You could limit the number of ChromeDrivers that way, but you absolutely will not be able to only use a single instance. It just won't work if you spawn it from a web app.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't realize that. Your solution, along with adding ` var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");` when I was creating the Chromedriver has it working flawlessly. I really appreciate your help!